# Electronjs - Delete registry entries when uninstalled

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, registry, electron-builder

I need to delete Windows registry entries created by the application when the application is uninstalled.
The application is packed with electron-builder and i need to delete registry entries whether it is installed with .exe the with the windows store (appx)

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read this documentation https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html.I am building an application with electron-builder too but I had not yet asked myself this problem. Thank you :)
" deleteAppDataOnUninstall = false Boolean - one-click installer only. Whether to delete app data on uninstall. "

Answer (score 0):

you can add a custom nsis script in electron build. Use include option
https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html#custom-nsis-script

then you can add below macro in the script file

> !macro customUnInstall
>
> DeleteRegValue HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
> "SomeLeafLevelEntry"
>
> DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\XYZApp\AppTopLevelKey"
>
> !macroend

that should delete the registry values

More info : https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Registry_plug-in#Delete_Registry_Key_.28same_as_DeleteRegKey.29

https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-197518.html